# Input field with default value that is not touched by user is empty string in form data on submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form and I prepopulated several input fields with default values

Here is the beginning of the form component where I set the value that goes in the message field.

```
function Form() {

  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

  fetch(message)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(text => {
      setMsg(text);
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm<Inputs>();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = data => {
    console.log("submit")
    console.log(data)
    reset();
  };
```

Here is the message input field (material UI component)

```
                    <TextField 
                      id="message"
                      className='inputfield'
                      size="small" 
                      label="Message" 
                      {...register("message")}
                      multiline rows={7} 
                      required 
                      value={msg}/>
```

When I click my submit button this value in the form has empty string.

However when I click the field, then hit submit, then the default value I set appears in the form data.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to get around it so that the value always gets sent regardless if the user touches the field or not.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that when you first load in, useForm doesnt know what the value is, but when you click into that input field, useForm understands that something has changed in that input field.
You will need to save the values from the API into useForm

```js
function Form() {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
  fetch(message)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(text => {
      setMsg(text);
  });

  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm<Inputs>({
    values: {
      message: msg
    }
  });
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = data => {
    console.log("submit")
    console.log(data)
    reset();
  };
```

check out `useForm` docs as they do give you a good example
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#values